# Model in model is null so modelstate is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a model in another model. When I try to check the modelstate it is invalid. This is because the other model in this model is null.

**Project.cs:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Toolbox.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public WorkPreparation WorkPreparation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**WorkPreparation.cs:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Toolbox.Models
{
    public class WorkPreparation
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public CentralHeating CentralHeating { get; set; }
        public Pluming Pluming { get; set; }
        public Ventilation Ventilation { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: The error I'm getting:]

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you use .net6, try to remove  `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in your project.csproj.